# css grid showing only one column instead of repeat(5, 120px)

Tags: css, vue.js, css-grid

I have a css grid which i am using it to display images like a gallery.
Here's the html part.

```
  <template>
    <div class="images-grid">
      <div v-for="image of images" :key='image.src' class="img-container">
        <img :src="image.src">
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

and css,

```
  .images-grid{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 120px);
    padding-top: 103px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .img-container{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: aqua;
  }

  .img-container img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

the grid is showing only one column like [image: this] instead of 5. I've tried using inline-block but i exceeds 5 columns. Am I doing anything wrong here? or does vue css works differently cuz I am new to Vue.

Comment: this seems to be a loading issue of your CSS file

Comment: how to fix it then any idea?

Comment: i think its not css loading issue.....its something else

Comment: share the generated code instead of the template one

Comment: Try getting rid of your `transform-style` and have a look

Comment: transform-style didn't effect anything i've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem...

I use gsap to animate the elements.

So gsap changes the display to block and then animates.This thing caused my grid to become block :')

lol I've spend past 45 mins or so on this.

thanks to Temani.